# determine file empty, $_FILES['file']['size'] OR filesize()

Tags: php

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] == 0){}
if(filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) == 0){}
```

Which one will be better way to check if input file is empty?

Comment: The first one will give you the size PHP wrote to the file, the second will give you the size as PHP get's back from the file system. The first will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. [Instead](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
```

This means a file was successfully uploaded. Following this you *may* want to check whether the file size is `0` or not as part of validating whether the received file is acceptable; for that you can use `$_FILES['file']['size']`. But you should be doing more in-depth validations of the file type anyway, e.g. with [Finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php), and the file size should be a lesser concern.